# Can you make profit from a miner?

Tags: mining-profitability, fraud

Someone named mr_richard665 on instagram told me he was a bitcoin broker that worked with bitcoingroup and that he could help me make 30% profit everyday from my investment if i let him manage my account by me sending my bitcoin investment to his miners wallet address,is this a scam?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is a scam.

The scammer has probably asked for your login info, so that he can 'set you up for mining'. In reality, **mining does not work like this at all**, the scammer simply wants access to your account so that they can copy down your seed phrase. With that done, even if you change your password, the scammer will be able to re-create your wallet on a different device, no password needed! The scammer could then steal your coins at a later date, after convincing you to 'fund the wallet for mining', etc.

DO NOT give the scammer any login or otherwise identifying information. There is **never** any need to do so.

Comment: If it was possible to get a 30% daily return, in one year you could turn a penny into more than three thousand billion, billion, billion, billion dollars. So no, a 30% daily return is not possible. But if you think it is, sure, go ahead and invest a penny. Next year, you'll own more wealth than exists on the planet. If you're conservative, invest just a penny and after two months, take out $30,000 to be safe. Anyone who had access to such wealth generation wouldn't want anyone else's money.